# Material 3 custom colors - How to generate tonal palettes?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, material-design, android-jetpack-compose-material3

The material 3 site has a section on [custom colors](https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/custom-colors).

[image: tonal palettes]
[Theme builder](https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom)

Is there a way to programmatically generate tonal palettes for a given (harmonized) color to override the color scheme?

```
@Composable
fun CardMinimalExample(
    customColor: Color = Color.Red
) {
    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.copy(
            surfaceVariant = customColor
        )
    ) { // inefficient? 
        Card() {
            Text(text = "Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}


@Preview
@Composable
private fun Preview() {
    CardMinimalExample()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following restricted method `Hct.fromInt` that seems to work.

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@ColorInt
fun getColorRole(@ColorInt color: Int, @IntRange(from = 0, to = 100) tone: Int): Int {
    val hctColor = com.google.android.material.color.utilities.Hct.fromInt(color)
    hctColor.tone = tone.toDouble()
    return hctColor.toInt()
}
```

```
    val hexColor = java.lang.String.format("#%08X", -0x1 and color.toArgb())
    Toast
        .makeText(
            context,
            hexColor,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        )
        .show()
```

[Here](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/compose-custom-colors) is a library built on this method.

```
data class CustomColorScheme(
    val color: Color,
    val onColor: Color,
    val colorContainer: Color,
    val onColorContainer: Color
)

fun Color.lightCustomColorScheme(): CustomColorScheme {
    val palette = tonalPalette()
    return CustomColorScheme(
        color = palette.color40,
        onColor = palette.color100,
        colorContainer = palette.color90,
        onColorContainer = palette.color10
    )
}

fun Color.darkCustomColorScheme(): CustomColorScheme {
    val palette = tonalPalette()
    return CustomColorScheme(
        color = palette.color80,
        onColor = palette.color20,
        colorContainer = palette.color30,
        onColorContainer = palette.color90
    )
}
```

Comment: Great find. I hope they finally fix tat issue in official library and make it public. This issue is open for a long time. You might add this as comment on the issue too.

Comment: @Thracian `CorePalette.of` uses `Hct.fromInt` behind the scenes, so the result should be the same (I think they disagree with the result from the theme builder itself). I tried your library again and it works (yellow40 = #FF626200) without the max(48) `Hct.from(camColor.hue, camColor.chroma, tone.toDouble()).toInt() // TODO max(48, chroma)?`. Even if the api is marked as restricted, I think it's fine to just suppress the warning.

Comment: @Thracian To clarify, I added `@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")` to ignore `@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)` from `import com.google.android.material.color.utilities`, but the functions are still public. Are you saying the results from the [theme builder](https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom) are themselves incorrect? (add #FFFF00 in "Extended Colors" for yellow, yellow40 used for primary color in light theme is #626200)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this [official library](https://github.com/material-foundation/material-color-utilities) but there is no kotlin  support yet but easy to copy paste and use code in kotlin.

I created a [library](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Extended-Colors) that returns M2 color swatches, M3 tonal palettes, color names and converts between HSL, HSV, and RGB.

To get tonal palette as list you can use

```
fun getColorTonesList(color: Color): List<Color> {

    val camColor = Cam16.fromInt(color.toArgb())
    val palette: TonalPalette =
        TonalPalette.fromHueAndChroma(camColor.hue, max(48.0, camColor.chroma))
    val toneList = mutableListOf<Color>()

    material3ToneRange.forEach { shade ->
        toneList.add(Color(palette.tone(shade)))
    }

    return toneList
}
```

or map that returns values between 0 and 100

```
fun getColorTonesMap(color: Color): Map<Int, Color> {
    val palette: TonalPalette = TonalPalette.fromInt(color.toArgb())
    val toneMap = linkedMapOf<Int, Color>()

    material3ToneRange.forEach { shade ->
        toneMap[shade] = Color(palette.tone(shade))
    }

    return toneMap
}
```

which uses official library but there still a bug that doesn't return correct palette for every color.

https://github.com/material-foundation/material-color-utilities/issues/21